# Easy-to-use AIML-compliant chat bot

Tags: linux, open-source, self-hosted, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Requirments:

1. open source
2. runs on Linux
3. implements AIML ([Artificial Intelligence Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML))
4. self-hosted

If a library, then Java based or at least runnable on the JVM.

I'd be glad to use a Java library.  Or, if there's something out there built already, great.  I just want to get into the `AIML` itself.  The underlying engine/software/library/implementation is of secondary concern.

---

*I see some links like [chatbots-library](https://github.com/codeanticode/chatbots-library) or [RebeccaAIML](https://github.com/codeanticode/chatbots-library/wiki/linux-installation-of-rebeccaaiml) and see mention of A.L.I.C.E and Rebecca as chat bots.  There are many repos, but what's available for install?  What's commonly used?  Just looking for something without the deep learning curve.  Preferably using all open source.
The specific Java library i've seen mentioned is the package `org.alicebot` which means, of course, http://www.alicebot.org -- which redirects.*

One of the more promising efforts in this direction is [program-ab](https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/) which I found through [datenhahn](https://github.com/datenhahn/python-aiml-chatbot) on github.  The `datenhahn` implementation [looks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/445903/17056) workable -- although a Java implementation would've been preferred.  (I suppose there's always Jython to run the bot.)

Ideally, as datenhahn points out, it's preferable to run a bot from [pandorabots](https://home.pandorabots.com/) locally.

Comment: I want to run pandorabot locally.  Or, something very like pandorabot.  Preferably runnable on the JVM, perhaps even Java based.  (not sure how important that is, but would like the bot to be able to invoke or hook into other software.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you are mostly interested in the AIML side of things I would suggest taking a look at the [Jupyter AIML Chatbot Kernel](https://github.com/paulovn/aiml-chatbot-kernel) in collusion with the [python-aiml](https://github.com/paulovn/python-aiml) package.

This solution is:

- Open Source
- Self Hosted
- Runs On Linux *(or OS-X or Windows)*
- Python rather than Java
- Ready to go
- Easy to install

Installation:

```
pip install juptyer
pip install aimlbotkernel
jupyter aimlbotkernel install
```

To run `jupyter notebook` and on the resulting web page AIML Chatbot kernel will be available in the Notebook New menu. Starting one such kernel will create a chatbot. The chatbot is initially empty but can be loaded with a couple of predefined DBs (use the %help magic for initial instructions).

You can see an example of it running 'Alice' [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/paulovn/aiml-chatbot-kernel/blob/master/examples/02-chatbot-alice.ipynb) which is one off the included example file sets.

Comment: The python is ok, but, *could* the bot invoke or hook into something in Java?

Comment: @Thufir of course it could - python is great at inter-language operation. In fact a lot of Jupyer is written in Java IIRC!